# Shaded relief looks metallic in blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, height-map

[image]

The shaded relief of the heightmap I use looks metallic or maybe glassy when I render. I set the principled bsdf of the plane below the heightmap to 0.000 but it still looks metallic when I render with cycles.

How can I solve the problem of the metallic relief?Is there some settings I still have to do?
The image attached is rendered on 30 samples cycles just for testing
How can I make the relief look realistic

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[2]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/PziCV.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PziCV.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AakYK.png)[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add an image that shows your shader node setup...

Comment: Okay. It has been edited. Thanks

Comment: Why do you think it looks metallic? BTW your image node has set Color Space to Non-Color ... any reason for that?

Comment: Can you give an example of the look you would like to achieve? @vklidu If the image is a height-map, that could very well be right. (The data is having  to be multiplied by 40 to take it to about 0-0.4)

Comment: @RobinBetts If I'm correct the height-map is still greyscale image, so I don't think it has a reason especially used as color input. Multiply is used just because height-maps are usually very dark (for their bit depth range) so he needs to increase strength. I lived in a feeling, that non-color is used only for vectors. In his case it seems displacement is done with modifier not shader.

Comment: Non color is correct if it is indeed a height map, it should not go through any color transforms.

Comment: Thank you all. I have edited my question and I have added the image I want to achieve to the question. Pls check it out

Comment: what do you mean by metallic? is the second image what you're trying to achieve? I don't see a big difference between the 2 actually... maybe explain a bit more?